# Invioce Online Payment for Anonymous Users?

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page, invoice

We would like to set up invoices that get paid online. We have set up Invoicing and a default Contribution Page, and it looks like we can get to the payment page for a specific invoice to using the following URL structure:

```
https://example.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1&ccid=xxx&cid=xxx
```

But this URL requires authentication when we include the ccid and cid params, it does not allow an anonymous Drupal user to access the page.

Is there a permission setting I'm not seeing? We have "allow online contributions" set for anonymous users, and they can see the contribution page if we don't include the additional "ccid" and "cid" query params. It's just when we specify the contribution id that it requires a login. We'd want to be able to have anonymous users pay their invoices without requiring a Drupal login. Is this possible?

Comment: have you tried adding tokens for checksum?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion, how would I go about adding tokens for checksum?

Comment: am sure a quick google for civicrm token checksum would help you find the documentation > https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge but perhaps that isn't your question and it is more about the context of what you are sending and how you are sending it?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion, I guess the issue here is the emailing feature for Invoices doesn't seem to process tokens (it doesn't translate them to values), so it does not create the actual checksum value ("cs=...") in the URL link. That's where I'm having trouble. The checksum gets processed correctly when sending a normal email to a contact in Civi, but doesn't when emailing an Invoice from the Contribution view screen. Is there a way to have Invoice mailing process tokens? Or is there a way to create a checksum value manually so I can include the cs query param myself when I send the Invoice email?